# pdflib 8.0 convert html to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

How to convert html to pdf using pdflib 8.0.

```
$html = "<div style='color:red'>Hello World</div>";
$signature = $p->create_textflow($html, "");
```

Doesn't work...

```
PDFlib exception occurred in hello sample: [1400] create_textflow: Unknown option 'div'
```

Answer (score 2):

PDFlib is **not a converter**, and **can not convert HTML fragments to PDF**. If you use Textflow, you must translate the HTML attributes into known PDFlib options. Depending on your input data, this can be a non-trivial task.